# QML multi-window application structuring approaches

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt-creator

I'm starting a new QML/C++ project. I'm pretty new to QML. I've developed some cross-platfrom application with Qt and C++, but I rarely used QML for UI.

I'm starting a new smartphone application (android and ios) that will probably have 10 or more different windows (I suppose to use different QML pages for every window). There will be a main page and then, depending on the button you click, other windows will be open so that you can navigate through all the functionality of the app.

What I wanted to know is: what is the correct approach of structuring a multi-window application with qml? How should I load my QML windows dynamically (when for example a button is clicked)?

I found [this really interesting topic](https://wiki.qt.io/QML_Application_Structuring_Approaches) that explains how to use *Loader element* to load different windows with qml (using a single Loader, using a Loader for every page, ...) but it's using *QtQuick 1.1* and now, with *Qt 5.15*, I'm using *QtQuick 2.12*. I was wondering if the *"More Complex Navigation"* approach in the link above is still the one to follow with QtQuick 2.12 for my purpose or there are better ways that promote efficiency, maintainability and readability of the code.

Comment: I absolutely don't see a problem in creating a multi window app with QML. Just like I don't see the need to use Loader. Use `Window`and [show](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#show-method) whenever you need to show a window. But for mobile devices I guess the best concept is using something like `StackView` or `SwipeView`.

Comment: I am just reading/learning form the book Learn Qt 5 from Nicholas Sherriff that is explaining the exact topic really good with a professional structured project in the book tackeling QML combined with c++ and the connections between it to make the technical stuff really efficient and the ui really beautiful, responsive, efficient and effective. 

I am not able to answer your question at this point but really recommend this book since as I understand you this will solve your question in a really deep and detailed and practical way.

Comment: @folibis yeah probably I will use StackView for mobile application, after a lot of searching it seems to be the best idea.